# boost :: asio server с простыми функциями

Tags: c++, boost

ребята, мне действительно нужна ваша помощь. Я изучаю boost :: asio и у меня есть 2 проблемы, которые я не могу делать за день ...

ЗДЕСЬ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ПРИМЕР ПРОСТОГО СЕРВЕРА, КОТОРЫЙ СДЕЛАЛ САМ

```
   int main(
{
    // crate a server, binding it and listening connections

    // acceptor server;

    //socket client

    server.async_accept(client, boost::bind(accept_handle, _1, &server, &client));

    io_service.run();

    return 0;
}

void accept_handle(const boost::system::error_code& eCode, boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor* server, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket* client)
{
    char data[43];
    client->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, 20), boost::bind(read_handle, _1, _2, server, client));
}

void read_handle(const boost::system::error_code& eCode, size_t bytes)
{
    char data_buf[20] = "hello";
    client->async_write_some(boost::buufer(data, 5), boost::bind(write_handle, _1, _2, server, client)); 
}

void write_accept(const boost::system::error_code& eCode, size_t bytes)
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket newConnection(server->get_ioservice)); // taking he io_service of the server

    server->async_accept(newConnection, boost::bind(accept_handle, _1, server, client));
}
```

***ПРОБЛЕМА Сервер принимает одного клиента и не принимает другого ожидающего клиента .. где я делаю неправильно здесь
ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ ... Я написал этот код в блокноте, так что извините за ошибки sintax, если есть некоторые
заранее спасибо за помощь!!!***

Answer (score 1):

`accept_handle` должен создавать новый сокет и запускать на нём `async_accept` после того, как запустит асинхронное чтение на старом сокете. Если у вас с++11, сокеты можно перемещать, если c++98 - проще всего использовать boost::shared_ptr для управления временем жизни сокета.

В `accept_handle` и `read_handler` у вас потенциальная проблема: вы создаёте буфер на стеке, запускаете асинхронную операцию, после чего выходите из функции не дожидаясь завершения асинхронной операции. Можно считать, что буфер будет удалён и асинхронная функция при работе с ним будет работать неверно. Для борьбы с этом буфер нужно либо напрямую создавать в динамической памяти, либо как поле класса.

P.S. Чем вам примеры из документации не нравятся? Они вполне нормально работают и позволяют добавлять нужный вам функционал.

P.P.S. Если вы хотите получить пакет именно нужного вам размера, используйте `asio::async_read(socket, buffer, handler)`